# Metal Deform in 2.8

Tags: physics, soft-body, rigidbody

I am trying to simulate a car crash in blender 2.83, but I am having some trouble figuring it out. I want it to be realistic, but also dynamic. I want to the damage to vary depending on the impact. I would also like the doors to be able to come off an deform. I mainly just want to be able to send a high poly car off a cliff and have it break. Any tips or .blend file would be great!

Comment: This interests me a lot, I hope a quality answer finds its way here :)

Comment: Hello and welcome :). Check some [YT videos on this topic](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=blender+car+crash), and then you can ask more specific questions here.

Comment: This is made with Fracture Modifier and Dynamic Paint (shows in the description): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3T-QapG7vAE

Comment: @ManuJärvinen how did he do that? I didn't find a tutorial.

Comment: Yeah :/ I don't know really, I might make a try. But here's a bit more tutorial-like nice video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AGsn6yysqbw

Comment: I saw that one. It does not seem to work that well in 2.8 though.